# How to use HtmlHelper.ActionLink() Extension Method in Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am curious how do I call the `HtmlHelper.ActionLink()` Method described in [LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493018%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) The following is my **Controller**, in an empty MVC Project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace TempMVC.Controllers
{
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(
                                   RequestContext requestContext, 
                                   RouteCollection routeCollection, 
                                   string linkText, 
                                   string routeName, 
                                   string actionName, 
                                   string controllerName, 
                                   RouteValueDictionary routeValues, 
                                   IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
           ); //OK
           HtmlHelper.GenerateRouteLink(
                                       RequestContext requestContext, 
                                       RouteCollection routeCollection, 
                                       string linkText, 
                                       string routeName, 
                                       RouteValueDictionary routeValues, 
                                       IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
           ); //OK
           HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName); //Error
           return View();
       }
   }
}
```

While I can use the `HtmlHelper.GenerateLink()` and the `HtmlHelper.GenerateRouteLink()` methods, I get the following error when I attempt to use HtmlHelper.ActionLink():

```
The type name 'ActionLink' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
```

Notice that I have declared `System.Web.Mvc.Html` at the top, and I see it listed in my **Web.config** file.

Can I use  **HtmlHelper.ActionLink()** method in a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ActionLink` is extension method that requires the `HtmlHelper` object. So you can create this object and use `.ActionLink` method:

```
var h = new HtmlHelper(
    new ViewContext(
        ControllerContext, 
        new WebFormView("name"), 
        new ViewDataDictionary(), 
        new TempDataDictionary()), 
        new ViewPage());

var link = h.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action"); // type of 'link' is MvcHtmlString
```

Comment: Thank you **YD1m**. This seems to be what I want, but I cannot get it to compile. I am attempting to use [ ViewContext Constructor (ControllerContext, IView, ViewDataDictionary, TempDataDictionary, TextWriter) ] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839461%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) How do I populate `TextWriter`? There is no overload without the `TextWriter` as you have suggested.

Comment: Try `new TextWriter()` and add `using System.IO;` directive.

Comment: Actually, `TextWriter()` is abstract. However I got this to work replacing your first line with `var h = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView(ControllerContext, "Edit"), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), Response.Output), new ViewPage());`

Comment: I see. Thank you for providing the tip. At least it pointed me in the correct direction :-)

Answer (score 2):

HTML helpers are used in Views, NOT controllers. The controller only passes data to the view.The view then generates UI for the data using HTML Helpers.

Comment: Thank you **Greg**. Unfortunately, my situation is a bit more complicated than my original post, which I simplified to explain my problem. I am using a Master Page with a master model - that I need to populate the master model in the Controller. I'm sorry I dont want to complicate things here.